# How to access git local repository?

Tags: git, version-control

I don't understand how to use git without pushing it to a remote in GitHub. I do the commit as it should but then what? How do you see each version and observe the changes if without push?

Comment: Look into using things like `git log`, for a command line option.  Actually, Git is sort of the reverse of what you imagine.  It was designed to be a fairly detached VCS, where you can do almost all operations _locally_ without the need to sync up with a remote server somewhere.

Comment: With `git log`, or `gitk`.

Answer (score 0):

because i still cant write comments... a answer

"git log" is the basic command to show the history, you can use tools like gitk, tig, or smartgit or the git gui itself to browse through the histroy more comfortable.

another "feature" even in local repos are the branches. you can have a working master, create a new branch for testing something out, and even after hundreds of changes and commits, you still have this one old working version. even if the new branch destroyed your project completely. and if the new one works good, you can merge it into your old one, have the history and another working version.

and even if you work the whole time on the same branch, you can use tags or lets call it versions. so you can have different release versions at the same location, and be able to access it whenever needed.